# "lernen" mit transitiven Verben

Tags: grammar, verb, verb-usage, infinitive

> Ich lerne sie kennen.
>
> Ich lerne ihn schätzen.

Mit welchen anderen transitiven Verben kann man das Verb "lernen" ohne "zu" kombinieren? Zum Beispiel kann man nicht sagen (so weit ich weiß):

> *Ich lerne Fußball spielen.

Mit intransitiven Verben ist es anders, denn man kann etwa sagen:

> Ich lerne schwimmen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***'kennenlernen'*** ist heute ein selbständiges Verb

Prinzipiell nennt man so etwas *'freie Verbzusätze'* (infinite Prädikatsteile)

> - sie lernten sich beim Tanzen kennen
> - ich gehe schlafen
> - ich gehe spazieren

Nach *lernen*, *helfen* und *lehren* kann der Infinitiv mit und ohne *'zu'* stehen!

> - ich lerne schwimmen
> - ich lerne Fussball spielen

'lernen' ist nicht intransitiv in diesem Fall ;-) -> intransitiv wären:

> - ich lerne aus Fehlern, ich lerne sehr leicht, ich lerne für eine Prüfung, das lernt sich leicht etc.

---

Du kannst z.B.

> - ***' lesen lernen '***, ***' laufen lernen '*** oder ***' jemanden lieben lernen '***
> - *'programmieren, reiten, sprechen'* etc.

Comment: "das lernt sich leicht": Wie kann das intransitiv sein? Das Objekt ist *sich*. Und was meinst Du mit "'programmieren, reiten, sprechen' etc."?

Comment: @boaten: Deine Frage war ***'Mit welchen anderen transitiven Verben kann man das Verb "lernen" ohne "zu" kombinieren?***

Comment: @boaten: ***'das lernt sich leicht'*** ist eine Floskel wie ***'das sagt sich so leicht'***! - **sich** ist kein Objekt sondern rückbezüglich - wie ***' er verliebt sich leicht'***...

Answer (score 3):

Wenn ich den Grammatikduden richtig gelesen habe, hängt es davon ab, ob lernen und das Verb einen echten Verbalkomplex bildet oder nicht. Echt in dem Sinne, dass regierendes und regiertes Verb ein Prädikat bilden.

Vergleiche:

> Ich lerne Geige spielen.
>   Ich lerne(,) Geige zu spielen.
>   Ich lerne, die Geige zu spielen.

Vergleiche auch den Unterschied:

> Ich lerne mit einem Computer schreiben (=er bringt es mir bei)
>   Ich lerne, mit einem Computer zu schreiben (=ich schreibe auf ihm)